# Tricky left outer join in EF for with criteria on joined table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity

I am trying to get the a list of Client records along with the most recent ClientNote record for each entity. If a client does not have an associated note, I expect ClientNote to be null for that Client (similar to LEFT JOIN in TSQL).

I have 2 related tables that look like:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Client](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientNumber] [varchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [AssociateName] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [AssignedToID] [int] NULL,
    [District] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ClientNote](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](4000) NOT NULL,
    [NoteDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TicklerDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [EnteredByAgentID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
)
```

I need an EF left outer join to return the Client and latest ClientNote when 
Client.Name like '%ike%' AND (either no ClientNote exists OR the ClientNote CreateDate is over 60 days).
So, I want back two objects for each match: one Client and one optional (null) ClientNote
I have tried so many things and I'm just not getting the results I seek.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following, you can also change the last from SingleOrDefault() to FirstOrDefault() or possibly into an array:

```
var clientInfo = (from a in yourdatacontext.Client
    join b in yourdatacontext.ClientNote on a.ID equals b.ID into temp
    from t in temp.DefaultIfEmpty() //this is what does the left outer join
    where a.Name.Contains("ike") && b.CreateDate > DateTime.Now.AddDays(60) 
    select new {
        a,
        t
     }).SingleOrDefault(); //or change to .ToArray();
foreach (var client in clientInfo)
{
    var client.a.t.yourfieldname;
    //or
    var client.a.yourfieldname;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work. I made several attempts to tweak it but was unsuccessful.

Comment: @user856806 What error did you get? When you say it didn't work what do you mean? If you want to access what was returned you'd do something like this: `var myAssociateName = clientInfo.a.AssociateName` or if you wanted something in the second table you could do a `var myNoteDate = clientInfo.a.t.NoteDate`

Comment: @user856806 I noticed that in your DB you had CreateDate as a DateTime field and the original query wouldn't have worked, I modified it to reflect your DB layout.

Comment: In the second criteria of the Where filter I get the pre-compile error "The name 'b' does not exist in the current context"  once typed in or compiled

Comment: I've tried changing out 'b.' to 't.' and the compiler is happy but then trying to get the data returned gives an error of 'InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains more than one element'  I have tried several other changes and am getting nowhere.  I've gone back to straight SQL on this.